# How to direct the visitor to certain http service according to their `host`?

Tags: nginx

I want to direct the users to different web services with nginx configuration.

The scenario is for the internal users with host name from `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.255` I want to serve them some web service but for the other external visitor I don't want this to be realised.

I know I could use `IP_TABLES` to enable this feature, but I use IP_TABLE rules mainly for firewall purpose, I don't want to mix it with this configuration.

Is there any configuration available to me in the `nginx.conf`?

Comment: What's your current configuration?  Is it just a small subset of the resources in your site that you want to restrict?

Comment: Yes, I want to restrict some scripts on the sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GEO module together with a map directive:

```
http {
  geo $special_service {
    default 0;
    192.168.1.0/24 1;
  }
  server {
    if ($special_service) {
      return 302 $scheme://$server_name/special-service/;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate `location` block that covers your sensitive content.

Keep in mind that configuration directives don't inherit; you'll need to include in the new block anything that's in the existing `location that's needed for your content.

```
location /path/to/sensitive/stuff {
    # any other config that you need goes here..
    # ...
    allow 192.168.1.0/24;
    deny all;
}
```